# How to access State from LG file in language generation feature of botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

As per these articles from LG file you should be able to access bot state directly, without passing values as scope:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-language-generation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-language-generation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

i.e. its mentioned:

> Language generation is achieved through:
> A Markdown based .lg file that contains the templates and their composition.
> Full access to the current bot's memory so you can data bind language to the state of memory.

One of examples there are looking like they are able to access variable 'name' from the UserState:

```
# greetingTemplate
- Hello ${user.name}, how are you?
- Good morning ${user.name}.It's nice to see you again.
- Good day ${user.name}. What can I do for you today?
```

I've tested it in few ways but I simply cannot access the UserState memory from LG file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k

It's not that you can directly access the bot state, but that the memory (and their scopes) in adaptive/composer bots are stored in state, and can be stored and accessed via scopes and LG. The key in in the article snippet you supplied is "memory" (In this case, referring to the adaptive memory scopes and their values).

For example, I can prompt the user for their name and store that in `user.name`. But that is not the same as `turn.activity.from.name` (which is not something from state, but is often saved into state). `user.name` doesn't get populated by default. You could of course take that value from `turn.activity.from.name` and store in `user.name` (maybe depending on the channel, or have other logic, etc.)

You can test this a bit more by using this:

#### Dialog:

```
{
  "$kind": "Microsoft.AdaptiveDialog",
  "$designer": {
    "id": "7zj5aK",
    "name": "GatherUserInfo",
    "description": ""
  },
  "autoEndDialog": true,
  "defaultResultProperty": "dialog.result",
  "triggers": [
    {
      "$kind": "Microsoft.OnBeginDialog",
      "$designer": {
        "name": "BeginDialog",
        "description": "",
        "id": "A25t0H"
      },
      "actions": [
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.TextInput",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "SOE0Ku"
          },
          "disabled": false,
          "maxTurnCount": 3,
          "alwaysPrompt": false,
          "allowInterruptions": false,
          "prompt": "${TextInput_Prompt_SOE0Ku()}",
          "unrecognizedPrompt": "",
          "invalidPrompt": "",
          "defaultValueResponse": "",
          "property": "user.name"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.TextInput",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "3sNA0B"
          },
          "disabled": false,
          "maxTurnCount": 3,
          "alwaysPrompt": false,
          "allowInterruptions": false,
          "prompt": "${TextInput_Prompt_3sNA0B()}",
          "unrecognizedPrompt": "",
          "invalidPrompt": "",
          "defaultValueResponse": "",
          "property": "user.gender"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.NumberInput",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "SsEiOF"
          },
          "defaultLocale": "en-us",
          "disabled": false,
          "maxTurnCount": 3,
          "alwaysPrompt": false,
          "allowInterruptions": false,
          "prompt": "${NumberInput_Prompt_SsEiOF()}",
          "unrecognizedPrompt": "",
          "invalidPrompt": "",
          "defaultValueResponse": "",
          "property": "user.age"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "CD7TVN"
          },
          "activity": "${SendActivity_CD7TVN()}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "generator": "GatherUserInfo.lg",
  "recognizer": "GatherUserInfo.lu.qna",
  "id": "GatherUserInfo"
}
```

#### LG:

```
# TextInput_Prompt_SOE0Ku()
 - What is your name?
# TextInput_Prompt_3sNA0B()
 - What is your gender?
# NumberInput_Prompt_SsEiOF()
 - What is your age?
# SendActivity_CD7TVN()
 - Your name is ${user.name}, you are ${user.gender} and your age is ${user.age}. You are also ${turn.activity.from.name}
```

And using Emulator, you might see something like this in cosmos:

```
{
    "id": "emulator*2fusers*2fa1464f41-f237-42dd-ad01-ca8fb150b97a",
    "realId": "emulator/users/a1464f41-f237-42dd-ad01-ca8fb150b97a",
    "document": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib",
        "name": "DanaVCosmos",
        "gender": "MaleCosmos",
        "age": 45
    },
```

Comment: Thank you Dana. I must say I am a bit confused. What is the format of Dialog you have posted there? Is it form BF Composer? Also if user.name is supposed to work, then should I configure UserState accessor as user and then add to it string type field named "name"?

Comment: Yes, from Composer. If you click "show code" in Composer, you can get this json format. It's the actual declarative dialog. I'm sorry; I might have incorrectly assumed you were using Composer as you linked to a Composer article, but you also tagged as c#. Are you using declarative dialogs or are coding them in dotnet/c#?

Comment: Yes, actually doing it in VisualStudio with C#. But planning to check composer in the future.